# How to add more than one extra argument to Redux Thunk

Tags: redux, dependency-injection, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

The following code block describes how to add extra argument to redux thunk.

In my case I am applying dependency injection and I need to pass more than one argument to the Thunk, so is there any solutions other than gathering all arguments in just one object and pass it to the **extraArgment** thunk property.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootReducer from './reducer'
import { myCustomApiService } from './api'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: myCustomApiService,
      },
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's literally the solution. You have only one `extra`. Of course you can make it an object and add all the things you need as properties. You could also pass a DI container in there or something. That's up to you.